# How to use find function for different value at each row of a matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

suppose I have values `need_find = [1 3 4]` and a matrix `A` in the size of 3xK. I want to find the values of `need_find` on its corresponding row of A. How can I apply vectorized solution in matlab instead of iterate over each row?

For detailed example as expected;

```
A = [1 3 4; 1 3 5; 3 4 5];
my_method_do_what_I_want(A,need_find);
```

The method returns

```
ans = [1;2;2] 
% so I find the index of each element of need_find at corresponding row at A
```

Long story short :seach 1 at row 1, search 3 at row2, search 4 at row3

Comment: Not clear, what is "its corresponding row in A"? Please, provide an example. Or did you mean A is K by 3.

Comment: A is 3xK matrix. 3 rows, K columns

Comment: You mean the index of the first element in each row that matches one of the elements in `need_find`?

Comment: @horchler not exactly, seach 1 at row 1, search 3 at row2, search 4 at row3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
A = [1 3 4; 1 3 5; 3 4 5];
need_find = [1 3 4]
[~,idx] = find(bsxfun(@eq,A,need_find(:)))
```

which returns

```
idx =

     1
     2
     2
```

This simple one-liner won't work if you have repeated values in the rows of `A` or if there are no matches at all, but I can only go by your example...